# AWS CDK with AzureDevops Pipelines failing with Error

Tags: azure-devops, aws-cdk

I've been trying to get this to work for few hours and not having luck. I can synth and deploy locally from my computer with no issues. But don't know to make it work with pipelines.

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
 - task: UseNode@1
   inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
   displayName: 'Install Node.js'

 - script: |
    npm install -g aws-cdk
   displayName: 'Install AWS CDK'
 
 - task: AWSShellScript@1
   inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'deployment-dev'
    regionName: 'us-east-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
     echo "Running validations"
     echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
     ls
     cd AppStack
     ls
     cdk synth -c env=dev
    disableAutoCwd: true
    failOnStandardError: false
   displayName: 'cdk synth'
```

The pipeline runs butfails on the last step.

```
 C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:2
${errors.map(e=>e.stack).join("\n")}`)}}static saveManifest(manifest,filePath,schema4,preprocess){let withVersion={...manifest,version:Manifest.version()};Manifest.validate(withVersion,schema4);if(preprocess){withVersion=preprocess(withVersion)}fs.writeFileSync(filePath,JSON.stringify(withVersion,void 0,2))}static loadManifest(filePath,schema4,preprocess,options){const contents=fs.readFileSync(filePath,{encoding:"utf-8"});let obj;try{obj=JSON.parse(contents)}catch(e){throw new Error(`${e.message}, while parsing ${JSON.stringify(contents)}`)}if(preprocess){obj=preprocess(obj)}Manifest.validate(obj,schema4,options);return obj}static patchStackTagsOnRead(manifest){return Manifest.replaceStackTags(manifest,tags=>tags.map(diskTag=>({key:diskTag.Key,value:diskTag.Value})))}static patchStackTagsOnWrite(manifest){return Manifest.replaceStackTags(manifest,tags=>tags.map(memTag=>"Key"in memTag?memTag:{Key:memTag.key,Value:memTag.value}))}static replaceStackTags(manife

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

My package.json is in the subfolder called AppStack with the cdk.json

```
{
  "name": "MyCDKProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CDK Project",
  "scripts": {
 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-cdk": "latest"
  }
}
```

Not sure what the error means or how to fix it. Any guidance would be appreciated.